# how to see the log file in android

Tags: android, logging

I want a code for creating the log file in android and at the run time where to check where this log file is getting created, I also example for the same in java

Can we create a log file using predefined functions in android itself

Answer (score 0):

You can start your own process of logcat on the device, and redirect the output to some file. This is the basics ( do it on a separate thread)

```
Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat"); // start process
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream())); // grab output stream
// store to file or print to screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) and [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).